# Bash script to monitor resource usage and email warning

Tags: linux, bash

I'm looking for a bash script to monitor resource usage and email if it exceeds a certain threshold.

so far i've got this

```
 top -b -d1 -n2 | grep Cpu | cut -c 35-39
```

but it outputs two values? ie

95.4
98.0

how do I add the email threshold part ie >75% i'd also like to add the same functionality for memory usage.

Comment: Read up on bash scripting, figure out how to do loops (hint: `while`), numeric comparisons (hint: `-gt`), and then post what you've tried again. Once you can print out a normal message, then look up the `mail` command, but you may find that configuring that to work with a typical email service is tricky.

Comment: you have multi-core CPU or your machine has more than one cpus

Comment: look at the other answers you have received to implement some logic about thresholds. OR consider installing a proper monitoring system, as there are several opensource systems that may meet your growing needs. Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

It's outputting two values becaause you're specifying two iterations with `-n2`

You're also looking at the cpu idle percentage, so you'd have to subtract that from 100 to get your value and since it's floating-point you'd have to use `bc`.

```
LOAD_IDLE=`top -b -n1 | grep Cpu | cut -c 35-39`; LOAD=`echo "100-$LOAD_IDLE"|bc` ; if [ "${LOAD%%.*}" -gt "74" ]; then #send email; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest user Nagios monitoring plugins for it. It will gives you more control.

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Operating-Systems/Linux/Check-cpu/details